# What happen with the unreferenced objects when a object changes their reference?

Tags: javascript, object, equality

By example,
I have two objects:

```
var obj1 = {x: 1, y: 2},
    obj2 = {z: 3};
```

Internally the variables `obj1` and `obj2` are references to objects like this:

```
|| variable obj1  || =====>  {x: 1, y: 2}


|| variable obj2  || =====>  {z: 3}
```

But if a do something like this:

```
obj1 = obj2;
```

the new state of variables is

```
|| variable obj2  || =====>  || variable obj1  || ====>  {x: 1, y: 2}
```

So the object `{z: 3}` is unreferenced.

1. What will happen with this objects?
2. When the Javascript interpreter will notice this situations?

Comment: It's called "garbage collection" and it happens automatically.

Comment: have a look at this: [javascript memory management](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection)

Comment: Actually the variable `obj2` will not point to the variable `obj1`, it will point to the object directly.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this question when looking for something similar and saw that it is not yet officially answered... So although the comments already give some context, there are some aspect that I think are not covered, so I will try to put these in a reply...

So let us go through your questions 1 by 1:

**0. So the object `{z: 3}` is unreferenced.**

actually this is not correct. It's vice-versa: By assigning `obj2` to `obj1`, `obj1` from then on will also point to the object behind `obj2`:

Before:

```
|| variable obj1  ||    {x: 1, y: 2}

|| variable obj2  ||    {z: 3}
```

After

```
|| variable obj1  ||      {x: 1, y: 2}
                        
|| variable obj2  ||    {z: 3}
```

**1. What will happen to this object?**

The object will be deleted as soon as there is no more reference pointing to it. As @Pointy and @Kevin_Kloet mentioned, this process is called **Garbage Collection**. If you want to know more about **how it works**, you can check out [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/garbage-collection). There is a pretty good explanation on this.

**2. When the Javascript interpreter will notice this situation?**

This is actually not defined in the standard and the behavior might differ by implementation. However it defined **that it will be done** and that it happens automatically in the background, so you don't have to care about it.

I hope that helps you (or anybody else coming along this question)